# How to remove the unwanted parent content type site column from the custom list definition

Tags: feature

I managed to create a custom contenttype(based on the item contenttype) using the feature with  five site columns.

Defined a list definition based on my above custom contenttype.

All of custom columns are available with the default item contenttype columns however i no longer need the default "Title" column. Either want to rename or remove from the list.

Is there any where i can define in the list schema to remove the unwanted parent columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the RemoveFieldRef-Element in your Content Type definition to remove fields of the parent content type. To simply rename a field you can add it to your content type with the same id but a different display name.

Answer (score 1):

At the list level, modify the content type settings so that Title is Hidden (will not appear on Forms).  Since you're inheriting from the item content type, it cannot be removed.  You can make it so it doesn't show up though with the above method.

I will also give it a default value so you aren't left with a (no title) context drop down list.

You're using a feature, I'm sure there's a way through code to to what I described through the GUI.  One of the devs should be able to tell you exactly.